# Subtract from Sum of same column Depending on Dates in SQL

Tags: sql, subtraction

I have My SQL Table with Resource Name, Supervisor Name, Planned Effort, Planned Finish Date, Task Name

I want to get the output of Resource Name, Supervisor Name and Planned Efforts where Planned Efforts is SUM (Total) of efforts for that Resource Subtract (Minus) from The Planned Effort's Finish Dates which are ending in the next month.

Below is an example:[image]

- Resource A has a total effort of 125%
- The output for A's Planned Effort by 5/31/2018 should be 50% ((50+25)-(25+25))
- Resource B has a total Effort of 100%
- The output for B's Planned Effort by 5/31/2018 should be 50% (50-50)

Below is the query i am using.
The Resource Name, Supervisor Name and the planned efforts are from different tables. I am using Inner Join to combine them. The current problem i have is, the query should give output for only those resources whose sum of planned effort is less than 80% after a specified date including all the conditions in where clause.

```
Declare @MonthStart Date
Declare @MonthFinish Date
Set @MonthFinish = '5/31/2018'
Select
r.resourcename AS [Resource Name]
--,ru.[Supervisor Name]
--,t.taskname AS [Project Name]
,SUM(a.assignmentpeakunits) AS [Occupied %]
from assignment a
Inner Join Task t on a.TaskUID = t.taskuid
Inner Join Resource R on a.resourceuid = R.ResourceUId
Inner Join Resource_UserView RU on a.resourceuid = ru.resourceuid
Where a.projectuid = '04D0A859-CFE4-E611-8109-0025B52F0120'
and a.assignmentfinishdate > @MonthFinish
and r.ResourceName <> 'Unassigned Resource'
and a.AssignmentPeakUnits < 80 
Group By r.ResourceName
Order by r.ResourceName
```

Comment: Your calculations are incorrect. ((50+25)-(25+25)) = 25, not 50. (50-50) = 0, not 50. It seems you rather want to add up the efforts after the given date. 25+25=50 for A, 50 for B. Correct?

Comment: You say you want a result per ressource name. But you also want to display the supervisor name. What if for one ressource name there are multiple supervisor names?

Comment: Hi Thorsten, please see below explanation for calculations

Resource A has a total of 125% Efforts, irrespective of the dates. If the query is executed with end date as 5/31/2018, the resource's planned effort will be 50% as his planned effort of 25% has ended on 4/30/2018 and 50% is ending on 5/31/2018.
Same is the case with resource B.

A resource has only one supervisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are thinking to complicated. You have these rows for ressource A:

```
planned_finish_date   planned_effort
2018-04-30            25%
2018-05-31            50%
2018-09-30            25%
2018-12-28            25%
```

You make clear that there is a total of 125% and that at 2018-05-31 25+50=75% will be done, so 25+25=50% remain and these 50% you want to show. But no matter what the total percentage, no matter how much is done, you simply want the sum of the percentages after the given date.

```
select
  resource_name,
  supervisor_name,
  sum(planned_effort) as total
from mytable
where planned_finish_date >  date '2018-05-31'
group by resource_name, supervisor_name
order by resource_name, supervisor_name;
```

(Your database is not normalized by the way. You say there can only be one supervisor per ressource, but your table allows for different supervisors per ressource. This should be two tables hence: a ressource table with the ressource name and the supervisor name and your plan table, but without the supervisor name.)

Comment: The Resource Name, Supervisor Name and the planned efforts are from different tables. I am using Inner Join to combine them.

The current problem i have is, the query should give output for only those resources whose sum of planned effort is less than 80% after a specified date. Posting my current query.

Comment: could not share the code in comments section, so edited the original question with code and requirement

Comment: Use `HAVING` in order to filter an aggregated result: `having sum(planned_effort) < 80`.

Comment: If Having is used, it has to be grouped by finishdate, resourcename & assignmentspeakunits, and that does not give the results for SUM()> The output will be individual rows without SUM.

Comment: I don't understand. My query gives you ressources with their totals. You say you want to restrict this to totals < 80, so simply add `having sum(planned_effort) < 80` after the `group by` clause and you're done. Why do you think you must change the `group by` clause?